# SoundCloud Top 50 Player

Tags: python, python-2.x

I wrote a Python 2.7 script, which plays tracks from the [SoundCloud Top 50](https://soundcloud.com/charts/top).

```
import atexit
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

import requests


if not os.path.exists('.tmp'):
    os.mkdir('.tmp')

@atexit.register
def cleanup():
    shutil.rmtree('.tmp')


class soundcloud_top50_player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.get_token()
        self.get_genre()
        self.get_top50()
        self.play_top50()

    def get_token(self):
        print 'You can get a token at https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=[...]&redirect_uri=[...]&response_type=token'
        self.token = raw_input('\nToken: ')

    def get_genre(self):
        genres = [
            {
                'link': 'all-music',
                'title': 'All'
            },
            {
                'link': 'alternativerock',
                'title': 'Alternative Rock'
            },
            {
                'link': 'ambient',
                'title': 'Ambient'
            },
            {
                'link': 'classical',
                'title': 'Classical'
            },
            {
                'link': 'country',
                'title': 'Country'
            },
            {
                'link': 'danceedm',
                'title': 'Dance & EDM'
            },
            {
                'link': 'dancehall',
                'title': 'Dancehall'
            },
            {
                'link': 'deephouse',
                'title': 'Deep House'
            },
            {
                'link': 'disco',
                'title': 'Disco'
            },
            {
                'link': 'drumbass',
                'title': 'Drum & Bass'
            },
            {
                'link': 'dubstep',
                'title': 'Dubstep'
            },
            {
                'link': 'electronic',
                'title': 'Electronic'
            },
            {
                'link': 'folksingersongwriter',
                'title': 'Folk & Singer-Songwriter'
            },
            {
                'link': 'hiphoprap',
                'title': 'Hip-hop & Rap'
            },
            {
                'link': 'house',
                'title': 'House'
            },
            {
                'link': 'indie',
                'title': 'Indie'
            },
            {
                'link': 'jazzblues',
                'title': 'Jazz & Blues'
            },
            {
                'link': 'latin',
                'title': 'Latin'
            },
            {
                'link': 'metal',
                'title': 'Metal'
            },
            {
                'link': 'piano',
                'title': 'Piano'
            },
            {
                'link': 'pop',
                'title': 'Pop'
            },
            {
                'link': 'rbsoul',
                'title': 'R&B & Soul'
            },
            {
                'link': 'reggae',
                'title': 'Reggae'
            },
            {
                'link': 'reggaeton',
                'title': 'Reggaeton'
            },
            {
                'link': 'rock',
                'title': 'Rock'
            },
            {
                'link': 'soundtrack',
                'title': 'Soundtrack'
            },
            {
                'link': 'techno',
                'title': 'Techno'
            },
            {
                'link': 'trance',
                'title': 'Trance'
            },
            {
                'link': 'trap',
                'title': 'Trap'
            },
            {
                'link': 'triphop',
                'title': 'Triphop'
            },
            {
                'link': 'world',
                'title': 'World'
            }
        ]

        print '\nWhat genre do you want to play?\n'

        for genre in genres:
            print '- ' + genre['link'] + ' (' + genre['title'] + ')'

        self.genre = raw_input('\nGenre: ')

    def get_top50(self):
        self.top50 = requests.get('https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/charts?kind=top&genre=soundcloud:genres:' + self.genre + '&limit=50&oauth_token=' + self.token).json()

    def play_top50(self):
        for track in self.top50['collection']:
            track = track['track']
            if track['streamable']:
                stream_url = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/' + str(track['id']) + '/stream?client_id=[...]&client_secret=[...]'
                self.stream_track(stream_url, track)

    def stream_track(self, url, track):
        filename = '.tmp/' + str(track['id']) + '.mp3'
        data = requests.get(url)
        with open(filename, 'wb') as code:
            code.write(data.content)
        print '\nPlaying "' + track['title'] + '" by "' + track['user']['username'] + '"\n'
        if os.name == 'nt':
            subprocess.call(['mpg123-1.23.0-static-x86/mpg123.exe', filename])
        else:
            subprocess.call(['mpg123', filename])
        os.remove(filename)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    soundcloud_top50_player()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your use of a class here seems unnecessary. You call it like a function, it calls a series of functions and never really operates like a class. It seems like you're mostly using it to deal with scope, but I would propose you instead make a function like this:

```
def soundcloud_top50_player:
    token = get_token()
    genre = get_genre()
    top50 = get_top50(token, genre)
    play_top50(top50)
```

Now you can just return `token`, `genre` and `top50` rather than having to assign them as class members for a class that's really just a function.

```
def get_token():
    print 'You can get a token at https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=[...]&redirect_uri=[...]&response_type=token'
    return raw_input('\nToken: ')
```

The way you build the genres is also strange. It should really be a constant instead of a list you build every time `get_genre` is called. It would also be a lot easier if you built them with a list comprehension, like this:

```
GENRE_PAIRS = [
               ('all-music', 'All'), ('alternativerock', 'Alternative Rock'),
               ('ambient', 'Ambient'), ('classical', 'Classical'),
               ('country', 'Country'), ('danceedm', 'Dance & EDM'),
               ...
              ]
GENRES = [{'link': link, 'title': title} for link, title in GENRE_PAIRS]
```

This makes it easier to add more, and guides against accidental typos in the keys if you put `linj` for instance. It also makes `get_genre` a lot shorter:

```
def get_genre():
    print '\nWhat genre do you want to play?\n'

    for genre in GENRES:
        print '- ' + genre['link'] + ' (' + genre['title'] + ')'

    return raw_input('\nGenre: ')
```

It's a strange function now, because you're telling the user to enter one of the `link`s you have but then you just trust that the text matches a genre. You could run a while loop over the input and only accept a value when it's a valid genre. If not that you should at least catch errors from invalid URLs being passed to `get_top50` so that you can give the user a more relevant error message about an invalid genre entry.